# css transparent triangle with border

Tags: css, border

Is it possible to style(skew) triangle like on the picture on the right side?
http://s15.postimg.org/h2vruavmz/triangle.jpg

I want to skew it, make background transparency 0.5 and hide bottom border of the triangle.

```css
body {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.arrow_box {
 position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 40px;
 background: #fff;
 /*border: 1px solid #ffffff;*/
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
 bottom: 100%;
 left: 50%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
 border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 border-bottom-color: #fff;
 border-width: 20px;
 margin-left: -20px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
 border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
 border-bottom-color: #000;
 border-width: 21px;
 margin-left: -21px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow_box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `transform: skew(60deg,0deg);` on the `:before` and `:after`

```css
body {
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.arrow_box {
 position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 40px;
 background: #fff;
 /*border: 1px solid #ffffff;*/
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
 bottom: 100%;
 left: 50%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
    transform: skew(60deg,0deg);
}

.arrow_box:after {
 border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 border-bottom-color: #fff;
 border-width: 20px;
 margin-left: -12px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
 border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
 border-bottom-color: #000;
 border-width: 24px;
 margin-left: -21px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow_box"></div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2266Lvz/1/)

I don't think you'd be able to make that background transparent easily with the technique you have used to draw triangles. You should use *png* image if you can.

Comment: Ok, thanx, that was the solution. But when I want to make border-bottom-color white and transparent 0.3 "rgba(255, 255, 255, .3)" it remains solid white. When I change border-bottom-color to rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) it works well, but i don't want to make it black and transparent, I want to make it white and transparent. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

The method you are currently using means that you will not be able to set a semi transparent "background" on the triangle. This is because the black borders of the triangle are actually a slightly larger separate triangle, it just happens that the smaller white triangle is overlaying its center. If you modify the white triangle's opacity then you will just peek through to the black triangle.

This can be avoided by using another method to create the triangle. The general principle is to create a box then turn it on its side using `transform: rotate(45deg);`. Using `overflow: hidden;` on the container you can cut off half of the box to leave you with a triangle without a bottom border.

You can then skew the container using `transform: skewX(55deg);` to push the triangle to one side.

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.arrow_box {
  height: 17px;
  left: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  transform: skewX(55deg);
  width: 34px;
}
.arrow_box:after {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); 
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  content: " ";
  height: 20px;
  left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow_box"></div>
```